# Firebase Hosting How to put multiple links in Access Control Allow Origin Header

Tags: firebase, http-headers, firebase-hosting

So I am limiting the amount of sites that can access my website. I found there's a header option in [Firebase Hosting section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-headers). I have two questions. First is how to put **multiple** links in the `value` of this header. Say for example, I want to allow Google and YouTube to access my site's resources. My other question is by replacing the `.@(eot....)` to just an asterisk, will the header be the same for all the files included in this directory?

```
"headers": [ {
    "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
    "headers" : [ {
      "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value" : "*"
    } ]
  }
```

I already tried placing this inside `value` but I have no luck in making it work as I get an error message.

```
// attempt 1
PROJECTNAMEANDCODEHERE.firebaseapp.com https://us-central1-PROJECTNAMEANDCODEHERE.cloudfunctions.net

// attempt 2
PROJECTNAMEANDCODEHERE.firebaseapp.com, https://us-central1-PROJECTNAMEANDCODEHERE.cloudfunctions.net
```

Error:
[image]

Note: I re-upload my headers every time I make an update on the `firebase.json` file. Please do not reference me with Firebase Cloud as I am NOT working with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` [supports two values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

- `*` to allow any site.
- `<origin>` to allow that specific origin access.

If you want `https://app.example.com` to be allowed the response value must be `https://app.example.com`.

Multiple values are not supported. If you want a limited number of allowed origins, the server must parse the `Origin` header of incoming requests and dynamically set the the ACAO response header.

Firebase Hosting does not allow for this dynamic setup without the use of Functions.

Comment: you said Firebase Hosting does not allow this setup without the use of Functions. Can you provide me a solution or a reference wherein Functions are used to allow multiple specific origin access? Another question. Would it be easier for me if I were to just upload my website on a web host separate from the Firebase link (`PROJECTNAMEANDCODE.firebaseapp.com`) and place my `.htaccess` file?

Comment: For Functions you basically take a simple NodeJS server that just takes a request and returns your HTML. While it's doing that it would look at the Origin header and allow/reject the request. I don't think a `.htaccess` file would be enough, you sould probably need some server logic or an Apache module.